# Renaming certain multiple values in a column of dataframe into another single value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data Frame, which is 1 GB in size, the following is a dummy one

```
df <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B", "C","D","E","F","G","H"), each=4),height=sample(100:150, 16))
df
   group height
1      A    105
2      A    119
3      B    108
4      B    114
5      C    109
6      C    111
7      D    148
8      D    121
9      E    133
10     E    101
11     F    143
12     F    135
13     G    147
14     G    141
15     H    150
16     H    145
```

And What I am aiming is to change the names of the column group like say for example all B, H, and G into NC and all A  into PC, and others into NON
and so I tried the following one-liner.

```
de=c("B")
df =df$group[df$group %in% de,]<-"NC"
```

But it's throwing the following error,

```
Error in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$group %in% de, , value = "nc") : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$group %in% de, , value = "nc") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

In the end, the data frame df should look like this

```
df
   group height
1      PC    105
2      PC    119
3      NC    108
4      NC   114
5      NON    109
6      NON    111
7      NON    148
8      NON    121
9      NON    133
10     NON    101
11     NON    143
12     NON   135
13     NC    147
14     NC    141
15     NC    150
16     NC    145
```

Any suggestion in R or pandas  would be really great.
Thank you

Comment: Actually, My data frame is quite large  and it has more values than A,B, and C. I can edit my question sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you can try:

Transform to character first and then replace the value directly.

```
df$group <- as.character(df$group); 
df$group[df$group %in% c("B")] <- "NC"
```

Edit:

As you updated your question you can try `ifelse`. Of course you can also overwrite the `group` column by this approach.

```
df$group2 <- ifelse( df$group %in% c("B", "H", "G"), "NC", ifelse(df$group %in% c("A"), "PC", "NON"))
head(df, 10)
   group height group2
1      A    139     PC
2      A    114     PC
3      A    132     PC
4      A    141     PC
5      B    107     NC
6      B    101     NC
7      B    122     NC
8      B    129     NC
9      C    100    NON
10     C    108    NON
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas/Numpy solution with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and boolean mask:

```
print (df['group'] =='B')
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
Name: group, dtype: bool

df['group'] = np.where(df['group'] == 'B','NC','PC')
print (df)

   group  height
1     PC     113
2     PC     118
3     PC     128
4     PC     143
5     NC     109
6     NC     141
7     NC     142
8     NC     129
9     PC     127
10    PC     102
11    PC     108
12    PC     107
```

Solution with double `np.where`:

```
df['group'] = np.where(df['group'].isin(['B','G','H']), 'NC',
              np.where(df['group'] == 'A', 'PC', 'NON'))

print (df)
   group  height
1     PC     105
2     PC     119
3     NC     108
4     NC     114
5    NON     109
6    NON     111
7    NON     148
8    NON     121
9    NON     133
10   NON     101
11   NON     143
12   NON     135
13    NC     147
14    NC     141
15    NC     150
16    NC     145
```

Comment: Sorry could you please take a look into my question ., I have edited it now

Comment: Yes, `NON` means `NaN` Not a Number?

Comment: NOT Nan ..Its a string

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace the group names as below

```
    df$group=as.character(df$group)
    df$group[c(3:4,13:16)]='NC'
    df$group[c(1:2)]='PC'
    df$group[c(5:12)]='NON'
```